# SQL select the entity with most instances of another entity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, many-to-many

So I have these two tables 'Subscription' and 'Show' which are linked via many-to-many 
[link to the ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNFnb.png)

How would I go about writing a SQL script that would tell me which Subscription has the most Shows included. Obviously subscriptions have different ammounts of shows included depending on the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try this but I think it might work

```
SELECT * from Subscription
WHERE id=(SELECT subscription_id
FROM Show_has_Subscription 
GROUP BY subscription_id
ORDER BY COUNT(subscription_id) DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can try this query:

```
select s.id, count(ss.show_id) as showcount
from subscription s, subscription_show ss
where s.id = ss.subcription_id
group by s.id, ss.show_id
order by showcount desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would seem to be one that doesn't require a `join` or a subquery:

```
select ss.subcription_id, count(*) as showcount
from subscription_show ss
group by ss.subcription_id
order by showcount desc
limit 1;
```